# Magento 2 nested blocks

Tags: block, magento2

I'm migrating from Magento 1.x to Magento 2

I created default.xml file to customize the existing layout.

My situation is that I have a div named "main-header" and I want a nested div inside it named "menu".

Now, I know blocks can have templates. So I tried to create a nested block structure (don't know if it is valid in Magento 2) :

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="common-header" label="Header common to all pages" as="common-header" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="main-header">
            <block class="Mymodule\Test\Block\Header" template="header/top_header.phtml">
                <block name="header.menu" class="Mymodule\Test\Block\Menu" template="header/menu.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
```

In the top_header.phtml, I'm trying to call:

```
<?php $block->getChildHtml('header.menu'); ?>
```

I know the above statement I took from Magento 1.x

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Silly mistake, I was missing echo:

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('header.menu'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a nested containers instead, that should work fine, you can add any classes you want and use any tag for wrapping.